# Generating PDF reports within javascript MVC framework (Backbone.js)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, pdf, backbone.js, report

I have a Backbone Marionette single page application with RESTful API backend (RoR).

I'd like to enable users to export a PDF report which would contain specific rendered views, regions and D3 graphs (basically the same they could see on the website, just rendered to PDF).

Is there any good way to do it? I know I could just make a screenshot, but that isn't what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I have used a [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) instance running server-side for this in the past. The application was based on Backbone.js and had SVG charts (Highcharts) so it would presumably work with D3. The [screen capture](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Screen-Capture) capability supports several formats including PDF.

If the pages you want to export require authentication, or have some dependency on user session, you'll need to figure out some way to spoof the users' session when accessing the page with Phantom.